# How to find the div id name?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="dice" id="dice"></div>
  <div id="main_div"></div>
</div>
```

In `#main_div` I have inserted 100 divs with different ids by using jQuery.

```
$(".dice").click(function(){
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
        $(".dice").html("<img src='"+ path + images[i] +"'>");
        total = (i + 1);
        player_A +=  total;
        $("#main_div div").each(function(){
            var $id_value = $("div").attr('id');
            if($id_value == container){
                alert("yes");
                }else{
                    alert("No");}
            });
    });
```

If i click `.dice` continuously, "**player_A**" value is increased. What I want exactly is if "**player_A**" value is equal to the `#main_div`'s "id" value, I need `alert("Yes")` or that "id" block BG changed.

Please check the fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsivelaga/8t87g5tt/).

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```
    $("#main_div div").each(function(){
        var id_value = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
        if(id_value == player_A){
            //alert("yes!");
            $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
        }else{
            $(this).css("background-color", "white");
        }
    });
```

I change the background color like you ask too :)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8t87g5tt/3/

Answer (score 0):

with your selector `$("div").attr("id")` you will get all div ids...

use `$(this).attr("id")` instead to get the "each div"...

Answer (score 0):

Try that with your js fiddle

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var path = "http://www.simplemailerresponsive.bugs3.com/images/dices/" , images = ["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","5.png","6.png"], i = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length), total, player_A = 0;

    $(".dice").append("<img src='"+ path + images[i] +"'>");

    for(var j=1;j<=100;j++){
        $("#main_div").append("<div class='cell' id='"+j+"'>"+j+"</div>");
        if(j%10 == 0) {
            $("#main_div").append("<div class='clear'></div>");
        }


      }

       $(".dice").click(function(){
            $("#"+player_A).removeClass("red");
            i = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
            $(".dice").html("<img src='"+ path + images[i] +"'>");
            total = (i + 1);
            player_A +=  total;
            console.log(player_A);
            $("#"+player_A).addClass("red");
         });
});
```